# gmp_pow() will not accept a GMP number for exponent

Tags: php, cryptography, numbers, rsa, gmp

I am playing around in PHP with RSA and big numbers.  I need to be able to take numbers to the power of an exponent that has ~256 to ~512 bytes using gmp_pow().  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: OK, so what's the problem? PHP does have a GMP wrapper for integers: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-pow.php By the way, are you **sure** the result of the operation you mentioned actually fits in the memory of your PC, and, more specifically, in the memory limit configured in your php.ini? 512 bytes sounds like a huge exponent and the operation itself might not be feasible, ignoring memory constraints.

Comment: The function gmp_pow() only takes a long value.  It will not take a GMP resource.

Comment: Well, that does make sense. Just think about how much storage space does 2^(64 bit number) require and I highly doubt that you have a datacenter at your disposal :) Are you sure you don't need to do [modular exponentiation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-powm.php)?

Comment: What should I use for the modulus parameter?

Comment: Well, that depends on what you're trying to implement. Just give this page a read first: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation

Comment: I'm trying to implement basic RSA (for experimentation, not production use).  I am not quite sure what I need to put for the modulus.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.rajorshi.net/old/code_rsa.htm Let me know if you have issues understanding it.

Comment: Oh, I understand.  I thought it had to be implemented on the exponent, but it is used directly to compute C=M^e (mod n).

Comment: Yeap. I just hope that you don't plan to use the encryption method that you're implementing in production somewhere :)

Comment: @MihaiTodor, No I will not be using this.  It was just harmless play.  I understand that this is bad to use in production, but why is it bad to use?

Comment: First of all, this simple encryption is not randomized and this is bad, because an attacker will be able to recognize that two ciphertexts contain the same encrypted data. Thus, you would be vulnerable to replay attacks. Look into padded RSA and Paillier if you want to implement randomized PK encryption. Still, DON'T use it in production, because it's very likely that your code contains vulnerabilities that are hard to detect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use gmp_powm() which automatically reduces the intermediate values to be less than the modulus value. This exactly what you want for RSA.

gmp_pow() doesn't accept an exponent large than a long since the intermediate values will be larger than the addressable memory in your computer.

Comment: What should I use for the modulus parameter?

Comment: The modulus is the product of the two secret primes. Depending on the notation, this is either n or p*q.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  This is working a lot better than what I had, but there is a problem with it.  It only works if I use 64-bit encryption or below.  Anything above that will not decrypt correctly.

Comment: Disregard that.  I found the issue.