# Big numbers (powers of powers ...) without PHP extensions

Tags: php

```
<?php
$res = pow(5, pow(5, pow(5, pow(5, 5))));
echo $res;
```

Outputs :

```
INF
```

I know it cannot be stored in a 64 bit float, but is there a way to calculate this kind of big number ?
All my attempts failed (always this "INF").

EDIT : Yes, I know that this number is huge, and that's really what I'm trying to calculate.
Also, I'm trying to do it without extensions (unless I fully understand what the extension does and I'm able to code it myself).

Comment: The BC math wouldn't help here because the number is unimaginably huge. Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: don't evaluate to infinity; but instead seems to evaluate to False, which is more like 0 than infinity. PHP has functions is_finite() and is_infinite() to test for infiniteness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
As noted in the comments, the [GMP extension](http://php.net/gmp) may work, and may be more suited to integer math.

Another commenter suggested providing more information than links.  The extensions noted in this and other answers are better-suited than the standard built-in php functions for either larger ints or more precise floating-point numbers.

But... you may not be able to just chain the results together with `gmp_pow` the same way you did in the question.  For one thing, you need php 5.6 to use a gmp number as the parameter for gmp_pow.

For another thing, the number is so large, you might need to use gmp_powm, as explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16257607/3240)

**Original Answer**
You could try [BCMath extension](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php) although it may not be installed by default.   (although BCMath may be better for working with floating points rather than Ints)

Comment: Use the [GMP extension](http://php.net/gmp) instead. For integer arithmetic you should always prefer GMP over BCMath. (Much better supported and much faster.)

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use http://pear.php.net/package/Math_BigInteger/docs
It can be installed via pear

Answer (score 0):

These two will help
 - BC Math extension 
 - GMP library